# Proof of Fundamental Theorem for line integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

### Description

I've been looking into the proof of Fundamental Theorem for line integrals in Multivariable Calculus course officially provided by [**MIT(18.02sc)**](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/3.-double-integrals-and-line-integrals-in-the-plane/part-b-vector-fields-and-line-integrals/session-60-fundamental-theorem-for-line-integrals/MIT18_02SC_notes_29.pdf).
And the question is that at the final step, I could not follow how the transition in the proof below happening at the part below
$$\int^{t_1}_{t_0} \frac{d}{dt} f(x(t), y(t)) dt = f(x(t), y(t)) \rvert^{t_1}_{t_0}
$$

### Theorem Fundamental Theorem for line integrals

If $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{\nabla} f$ is a gradient field of $f$ and $C$ is any curve with endpoints
$P_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ and $P_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ then
$$
\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{r} = f(x, y) \rvert^{P_1}_{P_0} = f(x_1, y_1) - f(x_0, y_0)
$$

### Proof: Theorem Fundamental Theorem for line integrals

$$
\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{r} = \int_C f_x dx + f_y dy = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} \Big[ f_x(x(t), y(t)) \frac{dx}{dt} + f_y(x(t), y(t)) \frac{dy}{dt} \Big] dt = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} \Big[ \frac{d}{dx} f(x(t), y(t)) \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{d}{dy} f(x(t), y(t)) \frac{dy}{dt} \Big] dt = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} \frac{d}{dt} f(x(t), y(t)) dt = f(x(t), y(t)) \rvert^{t_1}_{t_0} = f(P_1) - f(P_0)
$$

Comment: Well actually you might be overthinking it as integration is the reverse operation of differentiation so $\int ... dt$ and the $\frac{d}{dx}$ cancel out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F(t):= f(x(t), y(t)),$ then

$$\int^{t_1}_{t_0} \frac{d}{dt} f(x(t), y(t)) dt= \int^{t_1}_{t_0}F'(t) dt = F(t_1)-F(t_0).$$

Comment: oh,,, sorry. I was being careless and too much focused on the point first term($\frac{d}{dt}$) and the last $dt$...
Thank you for your answer!